# syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF),how to resolve

Tags: php

i create statement in class,but syntax error and unexpected 'if'
this is my code

```html
$row->actions    = '
<div class="btn-group">
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
'.generate_button('activity', 'edit', '<li class='". if('.$row->status==1).'{echo 'hidden'}"'> 
 <a href="'.site_url('activity/edit_activity/'.$row->activity_id).'"> <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit </a> </li>').'
'.generate_button('activity', 'view', '<li> 
 <a href="'.site_url('activity/view/'.$row->activity_id).'"> <i class="fa fa-file"></i> View </a> </li>').'
</ul></div>';
```

so,how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if` construct doesn't work in concatenation expressions, as it doesn't return a value. You can use the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) instead:

```
generate_button('activity', 'edit',
  '<li class="' . ($row->status==1 ? 'hidden' : '') . '">...');
```

Another issue is wrong order of quotes (or unescaped quotes, if you like):

```
'<li class='". if('.$row->status==1).'{echo 'hidden'}"'>...'
```

The fixed version:

```
'<li class="' . ($row->status==1 ? 'hidden' : '') . '">...'
```

Finally, consider using a template engine such as Smarty instead of mixing HTML with PHP.

Comment: I would argue that using PHP within HTML is okay as long as it does not do any complicated processing or modify model data. I don't think you *need* a template engine to separate the responsibilities of your code. It does make it easier though. I personally quite like Twig.

Comment: @BenGuest, I personally don't like Vincent van Gogh's paintings, although they are considered masterpieces. The PHP code mixed with HTML and CSS may look like a masterpiece to somebody, but not to me. I just won't argue.

Comment: I understand it's a matter of opinion. I was just saying it's not bad practice to mix the two.